# What's the current way of including JS assets and their dependencies in Engines for Rails 5+?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't have much experience with new npm/yarn/webpacker crazyness in Rails 5. So what's the correct way to bundle assets plus their dependencies (like bootstrap 4, for example).

Before it was just a matter of moving entire downloaded js library in `/assets` and calling it a day.

Let's assume I want to include this datepicker in my Engine: https://github.com/chmln/flatpickr

How do I set it up? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get anywhere with this?

It seems there needs to be a solution where the host application can pull dependancies from an engines or gems YARN `package.json`.

That way it could merge all YARN dependancies together with its own and check if there are no conflicts, if not - Happy days.

A possible workaround is to copy the dependancies over from `node_modules` into the asset pipeline. This is pretty much the same as what was done previously apart from now rather than looking through each file to find the dependancies and there versions you can just look in `package.json.`

Comment: Answer is that you can't. There's some discussion about how to make webpacker handle engine's assets. We're not going to see anything that works until Rails 6 though. See how ActiveStorage does it (it's a proper engine within Rails now). All assets are precompiled and crammed into /assets